# While loop in Snowflake SQL

Tags: while-loop, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run while loop in snowflake, but I keep getting error
I need to loop through employee and store the result into temp table `tblChildren`

Appreciate your help in advance!

: `syntax error line 7 at position 17 unexpected '<'.`

Here is the code:

```
set ro  = (select count(*) from  tblEmployees);
    execute immediate $$ 
    
    begin
        set counter := 1;
        set iRows = ro;
        set EmployeeID = '';
       while(counter < iRows) do 
            select EmployeeID = TblEmployeeID from tblEmployees emp where emp.RowId = i
            insert into tblChildren 
            with cteChildren as
            (
            select  emp.tblEmployeeID as ChildId, emp.WorkEmail, emp.EmployeeManagerId
            from tblEmployees emp
            where   emp.EmployeeManagerId = EmployeeID        
            union all
            select  emp.tblEmployeeID as ChildId, emp.WorkEmail, emp.EmployeeManagerId
            from    tblEmployees emp
                    join cteChildren on emp.EmployeeManagerId = cteChildren.ChildId
             )  
            select EmployeeID as EmployeeManagerId, c.ChildId from cteChildren c 
            select i = i + 1 
            end while;
     end;
    $$;
```

Comment: Is this a script, or a fragment in a stored proc?  Regardless, seeing some inconsistent assignments of variables (unquoted strings, undeclared variables, integer assignments using "=" instead of ":=" ... please confirm if this is your entire script (and if not, please post in its entirety).

Comment: Looking at this further, I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish with this code - but this approach is likely not the right one performance wise.  Please explain what you are trying to accomplish, we likely can help you achieve it more effectively.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of errors in your script. I tried to fix them, and this one work but not sure if it works as you expected:

```
set ro  = (select count(*) from  tblEmployees);
    execute immediate $$ 
    declare
       counter number;
       iRows number;
       EmployeeID varchar;
    begin
       counter := 1;
       iRows := $ro;
       EmployeeID := '';
       while(counter < iRows) do 
            select TblEmployeeID into :EmployeeID from tblEmployees emp where emp.RowId = :counter;
            insert into tblChildren 
            with cteChildren as
            (
            select  emp.tblEmployeeID as ChildId, emp.WorkEmail, emp.EmployeeManagerId
            from tblEmployees emp
            where   emp.EmployeeManagerId = :EmployeeID 
            union all
            select  emp.tblEmployeeID as ChildId, emp.WorkEmail, emp.EmployeeManagerId
            from    tblEmployees emp
             join cteChildren on emp.EmployeeManagerId = cteChildren.ChildId
             )
             select :EmployeeID as EmployeeManagerId, c.ChildId  from cteChildren c; 
            counter := counter + 1; 
        end while;
     end;
    $$;
```

Comment: While this may "fix" the broken code syntax, the looping structure with the instantiation of a CTE in each loop concerns me - wondering if this could be better resolved with a self-referencing table and/or window function.  What would help is a simple explanation of what the author is trying to accomplish.